# Open text file from local system without using input tag in Bootstrap modal-body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my button-style anchor tag:

```
<a id="1" class="data btn btn-primary tag_cnt" style="top:144px; left:510px" onclick="showModal('data'); reply_click();" type="button" value="1">Abc(1).txt</a>

<a id="1" class="data btn btn-primary tag_cnt" style="top:144px; left:510px" onclick="showModal('data'); reply_click();" type="button" value="1">Abc(2).txt</a>

<a id="1" class="data btn btn-primary tag_cnt" style="top:144px; left:510px" onclick="showModal('data'); reply_click();" type="button" value="1">Abc(3).txt</a>
```

With the script used for Bootstrap modal:

```js
function showModal(data){
    reply_click();
    function reply_click(){
        var idd = event.srcElement.id;

        var title = document.getElementById(idd).text;
        $("#myModal .modal-title").html(title);
        $("#myModal .modal-con").html("paharagraph");
        $("#myModal").modal();
    }
}
```

This is a Bootstrap modal:

```html
<div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="col-md-7 modal-con" style="border: 1px solid grey;">
        hello<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 modal-cont" style="border: 1px solid grey;">
        hello<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I wanted to open different text file with click of different button created with anchor tag in modal-body. What should I do as I have tried all the methods but not getting anything. I want to open a file without using input box in modal-body using JavaScript.

Comment: You cannot get a reference to a file on the user's filesystem without some user interaction with an input file element or a drag and drop operation

Comment: but can't we give a directory to open the file with the name of the file... @patrick Evans

Comment: No, that would be a huge security hole. If some webpage could just give any file path and open the file without user interaction the webpage could read any file on the system without the user knowing.

Comment: but right now i am just using on my local system and i have to show the project locally. so if there is any scope of picking a file from local system then please help

Answer (score 0):

```
Use ajax for load external file :
```

[click here for demo](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load)

Comment: @pushkar can you please send the complete code embedded in my code